# preview callback not functioning

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app that needs to process every frame of preview in previewcallback() function, my code is like this:

```
Camera c = null;

        try {
            c = Camera.open(1); // attempt to get a Camera instance

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        Camera.Size csize = c.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        int mPreviewHeight = csize.height; //
        int mPreviewWidth = csize.width;
        Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureSize(800, 800);
       // parameters.setPreviewSize(700, 700);
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        c.setParameters(parameters);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, c);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        preview.addView(mPreview);
        final PreviewCallback mPicture = new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)  
            { 
                    try 
                    { 
                            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);//,opts); 
                            Log.i("file","Bitmap captured");
                    } 
                    catch(Exception e) 
                    {

                    } 
            } 

        };

        c.setPreviewCallback(mPicture);
```

But looks like the log "bit map capture" is never showed, this means the previewcallback function is not properly functioning, can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have an empty `catch` block in your `onPreviewFrame(...)` method. Why don't you put some logging into the `catch` block to see if `onPreviewFrame(...)` is throwing an exception? Never use empty `catch` blocks.

Comment: thank you for your advice sir, I just a log.i in the catch block but still no output from the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your CameraPreview class?

I presume you're calling `c.startPreview()` somewhere?